# Conversion of highlighted text pdf to postscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

[image]I am using ghostscript to convert PDF to postscript.

If I am converting pdf having hightlight and comment i.e., pdf containing simple text then it converts text properly in postscript. 
But when pdf has highlighted or commented text then it converts that pdf page to image.

I am using following command.

`gswin64c -o sample.ps -sDEVICE=ps2write sample.pdf`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the PDF file, which you have not supplied, my guess would be that the highlight, or comment, is using transparency.

The PDF transparency model is not supported in the PostScript imaging model, at all.

So there is no way to take a transparent PDF file and produce from it a transparent PostScript file. While certain minimal transparency features could be replicated with clever PostScript programming, the general case simply cannot be reproduced.

So when the ps2write devcie encounters input which involves transparency it renders the page to an image, and uses that as the page contents in the output PostScript program.